# convert JSON to array -flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

so im using `sql_conn` dependency on my flutter project to connect database to my flutter project.

im following the example in the flutter package site and using this method

```
  var res = "";
  Future<void> cetak(String query) async {
    var req = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    setState(() {
      res = req;
    });
  }
```

the problem is, `res` is showing an `String`like this

`[{"CUST_NAME" : "MY NAME"}]`

and i just want to show `MY NAME` later in `Text()` widget.

How do i parse `res` so i can get only `MY NAME` Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, and [read more here](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/parse-json-dart/)

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
var res = "";
  Future<void> cetak(String query) async {
    var req = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    var parsedJson = jsonDecode(req);
    setState(() {
      res = parsedJson[0]['CUST_NAME'];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
  var res = "";
  Future<void> cetak(String query) async {
    var req = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    setState(() {
      res =req[0]["CUST_NAME"];
    });
  }
```

Please try this let me know if it works for you if you need more modification then pls provide me with your `print(req)` so I can get more ideas and prepare as you want

Comment: i have triend this, but its not working, because `[{"CUST_NAME" : "MY NAME"}]` , Its not an array.